# BFS algorithm - shortest walk on grid with constrained steps

Tags: c++, c, search, breadth-first-search

The problem is as follows: A wanderer begins on the grid coordinates (x,y) and wants to reach the coordinates (0,0). From every gridpoint, the wanderer can go 8 steps north OR 3 steps south OR 5 steps east OR 6 steps west (8N/3S/5E/6W).

How can I find the shortest route from (X,Y) to (0,0) using breadth-first search?

Clarifications:

- Unlimited grid
- Negative coordinates are allowed
- A queue (linked list or array) must be used
- No obstacles present

Comment: I'm sorry, but I failed to find anything to explain in your question...

Comment: Any obstacles present in grid ? what are the dimensions of the grid ?

Comment: why are u not considering (8N/3S/5E/6W). I mean why only pushing north/south/east/west only once. Wouldn't that change the answer in BFS?? please explain ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question for future reference.

Psuedocode:

```
while (true) {
    if (destination reached)
        break;
    addToQueue(go north);
    addToQueue(go south);
    addToQueue(go east);
    addToQueue(go west);
    getNextFromQueue;
}
```

It should also be noted that the execution time for this application grows very, very fast, so test it out with small coordinate values. For example, the coordinates (1,1) gives 7 levels of breadth and requires 16384 iterations.

Comment: Are you sure this works?  If you're always adding to the queue N, S, E, W in that order then you'll have a bias.  After every four steps you'l end up 5 units more north than you started and 1 unit more west.  If your starting point happens to be north and west of (0,0) you're going to be moving away from it.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm for this problem would be:

For each axis, step towards it until your position on the other axis is 0.

Pseudocode:

```
while (x!=0) {
  if (x>0) x-=6;
  else x+=5;
}
while (y!=0) {
  if (y>0) y-=8;
  else y+=3;
}
```

However, I don't understand why you need to search for a route - it's not that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

As "thejh" remarked there's no need for a search, but your assignment calls for one.

A reasonable approach is

1. Analyze. Is it all *possible* for arbitrary (x, y) starting position? Checking the allowed moves you see that they can be combined to yield 1-step horizontal moves, and 1-step vertical moves, so the answer to that is yes (for your hand-in provide the details of this).
2. Figure out what "breadth-first search" is. Wikipedia is your friend (although, if you have access to a university library, I really do recommend Patrick Henry Winston's old *Artifical Intelligence*, it's really good, very lucid explanations). Try it out with some simpler problem.
3. Do the assignment's problem in just about the same way. Ask here if you encounter any technical C++ problem.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Concerning point 2: This is pretty much why I posted :) I've been looking around for explanations and code examples for BFS searches, but when I failed to find any I could grasp, I posted this problem because I understood what it asked for and how to implement and solve it using DFS (depth-first searches) but not BFS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer (really based off of thejh's answer) that uses a queue:

```
//set x to start position
//set y to start position
do {
  if (x<0) Queue.Push(8N);
  if (x>0) Queue.Push(3S);
  if (y<0) Queue.Push(5E);
  if (y>0) Queue.Push(6W);
  while (!Queue.Empty())
  {
    Move(Queue.Pop());
  }
} while (x && y);
```

It's convoluted, but follows the directions.